# Simple Protobuf-net code failing in MonoDroid with 'No serializer defined for type'

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-net, xamarin.android

The following code works as-is on WP7 and Windows, I am now trying to get it to run on MonoDroid:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class SSDTO {
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public Dictionary<string, string> Strings = new Dictionary<string, string>(50);

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public Dictionary<string, int> Ints = new Dictionary<string, int>(50);

    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public Dictionary<string, byte[]> Bytes = new Dictionary<string, byte[]>(10);
}

public class SettingStore {
    public event EventHandler ContentsChanged;

    private Dictionary<string, string> _StringVals;
    private Dictionary<string, int> _IntVals;
    private Dictionary<string, byte[]> _ByteVals;

    public SettingStore() {
        _StringVals = new Dictionary<string, string>(50);
        _IntVals = new Dictionary<string, int>(50);
        _ByteVals = new Dictionary<string, byte[]>(10);
    }

    private SettingStore(SSDTO source) {
        _StringVals = source.Strings;
        _IntVals = source.Ints;
        _ByteVals = source.Bytes;
    }
```

//Accessors removed

```
    public static SettingStore DeSerialize(Stream data) {
        return new SettingStore(Serializer.Deserialize<SSDTO>(data));
    }

    public void Serialize(Stream Target) {
        Serializer.Serialize<SSDTO>(Target, toDTO());
    }

    private SSDTO toDTO() {
        return new SSDTO { Ints = this._IntVals, Strings = this._StringVals, Bytes = this._ByteVals };
    }

}
```

The Exception I get:

> System.InvalidOperationException: No serializer defined for type: System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]
>     at ProtoBuf.Meta.ValueMember.BuildSerializer () [0x00000] in :0 
>     at ProtoBuf.Meta.ValueMember.get_Serializer () [0x00000] in :0 
>     at ProtoBuf.Meta.MetaType.BuildSerializer () [0x00000] in :0 
>     at ProtoBuf.Meta.MetaType.get_Serializer () [0x00000] in :0 
>     at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Serialize (Int32 key, System.Object value, ProtoBuf.ProtoWriter dest) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.SerializeCore (ProtoBuf.ProtoWriter writer, System.Object value) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.Serialize (System.IO.Stream dest, System.Object value, ProtoBuf.SerializationContext context) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.Serialize (System.IO.Stream dest, System.Object value) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize[SSDTO] (System.IO.Stream destination, ABC.SystemModel.SSDTO instance) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at ABC.SystemModel.SettingStore.Serialize (System.IO.Stream Target) [0x00002] in C:\CODE\SettingStore.cs:145

I compiled protobuf-net for Monodroid in release from the monodroid project in the source trunk, which I grabbed 3-4 days ago.

Comment: r447 is now available for download; please let me know either way whether this fixes this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this reported to me a few days ago; it is an accidental regression, due to the Mono KeyValuePair having different accessors than the .NET one, and the new "tuple" handling not agreeing that it is a suitable match (basically, in Mono they have private setters, which counted against it).

I will fix this *this weekend* and redeploy. My sincere apologies.

Comment: Huh, its always the tiniest things that get you... thanks! =)

Comment: @tempy for info, I've patched this locally - just running test suites etc. The offending Mono code: http://t.co/cfuhIVBK (protobuf-net was wanting "proper" immutable tuples)

Comment: Those unnecessary setters look so innocent.